# KonvaJS / HTML5 Canvas infinite scroll looping items - cannot clone stage and append to top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to create a KonvaJS canvas with a number of items (say 200), which is more than will fit in the viewport. Scrolling around the viewport works fine, but I want the whole canvas to appear to be infinite. Similar to this :  [JS Fiddle example here](https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj) So when you scroll to the top you would then see the bottom content. My plan is to detect when the browser is near to the top or bottom and clone the stage, then append it to the top or bottom of the original stage. Once this happens again, then destroy the original stage and repeat.

```
    window.onscroll = function(ev)
    {
        var B= document.body; 
        var D= document.documentElement; 
        D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;

        if (D.scrollTop == 0)
        {
            console.log("scrolled top");
            var cloned_stage = stage.clone();

            cloned_stage.setContainer("container2");

            cloned_stage.draw();


        }

        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            console.log("scrolled bottom");
        }
    };
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiksy/gsaorb82/1/)

This seems to do nothing however. I've tried playing around with the Y offset too but no luck. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Konva in stage cloning. The cloned stage is not properly attached to the DOM. As a workaround, you can serialize/deserialize it.

```
var JSON = stage.toJSON();

cloned_stage= Konva.Node.create(JSON, "container2")
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/gsaorb82/2/